# How can I create pop up window that loads when you enter the site?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popupwindow

I am struggling with this so if anyone have done this before, I would be happy to get help, because I didn't find any solution. I did this first:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

<!-- // Copyright 2016 Leave this copyright notice intact.
// The PCman Website Popup Window Creator 
// http://www.thepcmanwebsite.com/ 
function enter() {
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpermalink.php%3Fstory_fbid%3D1345717502122893%26id%3D1345708592123784','','height=240,width=550,left=80%,top=10%');
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="enter()">

</body>
</html>
```

And it's working well, but I need little different solution like this iframe below, only to be displayed as pop up window .

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpermalink.php%3Fstory_fbid%3D1346255332069110%26id%3D1345708592123784&width=500" width="500" height="287" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried many different options like javascript functions but it seems I didn't find right one. So if any one knows how to display this iframe in pop up window or pop up box on loading of the site, I would appreciate that help.

Comment: a lot of browsers block pop-ups now. and also a lot of users find it very annoying when they do pop up

Comment: Never used iframe based  popups, but can show you div based if you want

Comment: Well Pixel i can try that way, it seems even better. Only thing I didn't mention in my question is that website have it's content, and that div based pupup need to jump out and to be gone when clicked on the side. Just to be more specific if some one didn't understand.

Comment: @Vlada how'd you go? :-)

Comment: Great @Caelan Grgurovic, I solve the problem, actually you guys solved it, I used html, css and javascript code that Andrew Bone posted, now I'm just looking for code that allows lightbox to be shown just first time entering the site, not on every reload. This is my first time here so I'm little confused about votes and stuff like that, but I appreciate everyone's help. :)

Comment: @Vlada haha, you don't need light box for functionality like this :) you can use just jquery JavaScript and HTML

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic no need for Jquery, look at my code ;-)

Comment: jQuery simplifies it ;-)

Comment: adds a lot of bloat though, slowing down the site. As a general rule, I think if you can avoid jquery do so :-)

Comment: @Vlada if you've accepted an answer you can press the grey tick next to it (you can only pick one though) and then this is marked as answered :-)

Comment: Oh okay, i've done it. As I said, first time here so I am struggling a little bit. :) But problem is solved! :)

Comment: @Vlada did you see the comment on my answer? I gave you a solution for your second problem :-) using cookies.

Comment: Yes, I did, now I'm master of my pop up window. :) Thanks everyone and thank you @AndrewBone .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want (I think) is something called a lightbox. For a long time you've needed a lot of javascript or some Jquery to do this, but CSS is the way of the future.

Here's how I would do what I think you're asking

```js
lightBoxClose = function() {
  document.querySelector(".lightbox").classList.add("closed");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #EBB;
}
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
.toolbarLB {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
}
.closeLB {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.lightbox .iframeContainer {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 2px;
}
.lightbox.closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Webite</h1>
<h2>Wow isn't my website great</h2>
<p><strong>It just makes you want to close the lightbox so I can get it!</strong>
</p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">A Link to google</a>
</p>
<p><a href="#">A Link to no where</a>, but all the cool kids have multiple links</p>


<!-- the actual interesting bit -->
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="iframeContainer">
    <div class="toolbarLB">
      <span class="closeLB" onclick="lightBoxClose()">x</span>
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpermalink.php%3Fstory_fbid%3D1346255332069110%26id%3D1345708592123784&width=500" width="500" height="287" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I haven't really styled it much, you can use CSS to make it look however you want.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Lightbox is exactly what I'm looking for. And this is exactly the code that I need. So great, one last step for this to be ideally, would be some code that allows lightbox to be shown just first time entering the site, not on every reload. But you've already helped me a lot.

Comment: @Vlada Then you'll need to write some cookies, here you go https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/9t6g4tcx/ that writes a cookie and as long as that cookie is in their browser they won't see the box again.

Answer (score 0):

Have your popup already showing on your website when users arrive.

Put this little script just above your popup `<div>`. Once users arrive, and the site fully loads, the popup will disappear.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){ // on window finish load
        $('#popup').css("display", "none"); // turn off the popup
    });
</script>
<div id="popup" style="display: block;">
    <img src="spinner.gif"> // simple loading spinner
</div>
```

Ensure that you have loaded the jQuery API in the `<head>` of your page for it to work!

You can of course adjust the CSS and change the div accordingly to how you would like it :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
lightBoxClose = function() {
  document.querySelector(".lightbox").classList.add("closed");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #EBB;
}
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
.toolbarLB {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
}
.closeLB {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.lightbox .iframeContainer {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 2px;
}
.lightbox.closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Webite</h1>
<h2>Wow isn't my website great</h2>
<p><strong>It just makes you want to close the lightbox so I can get it!</strong>
</p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">A Link to google</a>
</p>
<p><a href="#">A Link to no where</a>, but all the cool kids have multiple links</p>


<!-- the actual interesting bit -->
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="iframeContainer">
    <div class="toolbarLB">
      <span class="closeLB" onclick="lightBoxClose()">x</span>
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpermalink.php%3Fstory_fbid%3D1346255332069110%26id%3D1345708592123784&width=500" width="500" height="287" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would appear that your answer is identical to the currently accepted answer. Mind explaining your reasoning?

Comment: Copying and pasting the answer will not make it a better option